# Windows service QuerySuspend never comes

Tags: .net, windows-services, power-management

I write windows service which periodically doing some work in background mode.
And when he doing this work, I should disallow computer to go to sleep mode automatically.
I set CanHandlePowerEvent to true and override OnPowerEvent method. I getting some PowerBroadcastStatuses, but QuerySuspend never.
So, when computer is idle then after some period I get PowerBroadcastStatus.Suspend, but I expect, that I should get PowerBroadcastStatus.QuerySuspend and in case my service is busy with his work I should return false and it's disallow computer to go to sleep mode.
Why QuerySuspend never comes?

```
protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
    {
        switch (powerStatus) {
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.BatteryLow:
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.OemEvent:
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.PowerStatusChange:
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.QuerySuspendFailed:
                break;
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.QuerySuspend: {
                return MyProc.IsIdle;
                break;
            }
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeAutomatic:
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeCritical:
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.ResumeSuspend:
                Play();
                break;
            case PowerBroadcastStatus.Suspend:
                Pause();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this scenario not working at all.
OnPowerEvent never called with QuerySuspend, and return value have no sens.
However sleeping mode can be controlled via [SetThreadExecutionState](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setthreadexecutionstate)

```
    [FlagsAttribute]
    public enum ExecutionState : uint
    {
        AwaymodeRequired = 0x00000040,
        Continuous = 0x80000000,
        DisplayRequired = 0x00000002,
        SystemRequired = 0x00000001
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern ExecutionState SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState esFlags);


    var prevState = SetThreadExecutionState(ExecutionState.Continuous | ExecutionState.SystemRequired);
    try {
      //some code
    }
    finally {
      SetThreadExecutionState(prevState);
    }
```